# "No module named plotly"

Tags: python, plot, plotly

My problem is very simple. I have installed it with `sudo pip3 install plotly` but I can't import it. I've already tried to reinstall it without effects.

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-9d1f271208ac> in <module>()
----> 1 import plotly.plotly as py
      2 import plotly.graph_objs as go
      3 import pandas as pd
      4 from pandas import Series,DataFrame
      5 import numpy as np

ImportError: No module named 'plotly'
```

Comment: What version of pip3 did you install it with and what version of Python are you running?

Comment: add the relevant to PYTHONPATH see [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/471168/249978)

Comment: Just to make sure: You installed `sudo pip3 install plotly` and not plotply as you wrote, right?

Comment: Indorman thanks for a good hint. I work in jupyter notebook right now and somehow plotly was sort of "hidden" from him when installed in bash. I just made a new project in PyCharm with my "notebook" enviroment and added plotly to interpreter manually.It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If this error occurs open Terminal and if you using different source like ZSH or something else change  it to bash by running

```
bash
```

in terminal and then run

```
conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/plotly plotly
```

and the problem resolves.